# how to center my text in msgbox in easygui (python)

Tags: python, easygui

I have created a msgbox with easygui and everything works fine except that the text inside the box isn't centered as your can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znVQX.jpg)

here is my code:

```
from easygui import *
("Please upload your Background picture", "Picture Upload", "Upload")
```

so is there any additional parameters I need to add to center the label text?

same question on how to add any background color or image? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With EasyGUI you can' do any of these at the moment. It is simpler to use however it isn't as useful as some other GUI's. I'd Suggest using tkinter instead as it has all of the parameters that you have just asked for.

Comment: thx for your answer, but how did they manage to center their hello world label in their documentation when you look about msgbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, there is not simple options for that but you can try and use spaces to center message in `Easygui`'s `msgbox()`.

**Note: It will be hard work, especially in large messages!**